# Quintessence: what are tracking and scaling models?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, dark-energy

I'm currently reading around the topic of dark energy, in particular [quintessence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintessence_(physics)), and I understand the idea of freezing and thawing models. In freezing models the potential is shallow at late times, causing the decrease in the equation of state parameter. Whereas in thawing models, w is frozen at -1 and deviates from this at late times.

However I have also read that freezing models can be categorised in tracking freezing models and scaling freezing models.

What is the difference between these two models?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0603057 or Amendola and Tsujikawa's canonical textbook Dark Energy: Theory and Observations also has a good section on this topic.